Where could a stale web page be cached?
A web page I frequent went down over the weekend.  I don't suppose it matters, but its address is https://indilib.org. When I attempted to point my browser at it, I got 403 errors. The site was eventually fixed, according to every other user of the site I was able to contact. But not for me!
Of course, I tried clearing the cache in my browser.  I tried several different browsers on my main computer running linux.  I tried it on a windows computer on my WiFi network, also on my IPhone and my wife's Samsung smartphone.  All got the stale 403 page.
On my IPhone, I turned off WiFi. I then was able to access the page going through my cellular service.
I called my ISP (Cox) to see if they might be caching the page.  The rep I spoke with yesterday hadn't even heard the word caching, but she tried to access the page and was successful.  She said she was on the same network that I was but I am not sure she knows that for sure.
My attention turned to my Google Nest Wifi router. I had lengthy conversations with "Google Advisors" who bombarded me with a lot of canned 'answers' that did not solve my problem.  As a last resort, I factory-reset the router. None of this improved the situation. The bad page was still being loaded.
I wondered if my Motorola cable modem caches pages.  It seems that modems don't cache so that's out.  In any case, I'd power cycled it before I power cycled the router.  The modem is a DOCSIS 3.1 Cable Modem Model MB8611.
I called Cox back and they want to GIVE me a Panoramic WiFi Gateway.  I am a little wary of Cox bearing gifts.  This equipment is a Modem-router combo. The research I did two years ago when I bought this equipment said that modem-router combos were inferior to separate components.  In any case, I don't want to set my whole network again for one stinking cached web page.  The Cox rep said I can use my own router. Okay, but I'm still suspicious that they're just throwing old equipment at me because they don't want to or aren't able to properly diagnose the problem.  They still haven't given me any explanation of what the problem is.
I wonder if there's anyone here who might understand what is going on and whether I should take the gift that Cox is offering me.
UPDATE: I no longer believe it likely that this is a caching issue. As Dr. Moishe Pippik points out, it could be something on the server side, one server that is not fully recovered from the original crash. Though what the site's network configuration might be that could cause this pattern is a mystery to me.
Anyway, with the knowledge that I have access to the site using my phone's cellular data, I have now finally become able to post my questions there, where they will hopefully be answered.
Thanks for those who helped me get to this point.

so no, it is not possible for a modem to cache a webpage. modems only deal with analog signal and the concerns related to it. they don't know a webpage from a hole in the ground. same with routers, unless that router has special modules for http proxy or http traffic inspection (and would only cache in the case of a proxy/ALG that was configured to do so). Personally i'd try an endpoint VPN connection see if that changes anything. if it doesn't then the issue is definitely with the endpoint device you are trying to use. also don;t assume the 403 is in fact stale, they may just not like you.

thanks for confirming my suspicion that modems don't cache. Well, to do an Endpoint VPN, I'd have to learn how to do that.  Is there a quick and dirty one I could set up on Ubuntu Linux? As for them not liking ME, how do they even know it's me until I try to log in?  Some of my attempted connections were on my wife's computer and they don't know her from Adam.

no in order for it to work the VPN would have to be a commercial service, so that it uses IP addresses that are not yours, and bypasses traffic handling on your devices like routers and modems (they just handle the VPN tunnel, not the HTTP requests inside it). if they have blocked you, it would be by IP address, and all your network devices share that one IP. this is kind of likely since you said you could get to the page by disabling wifi on a cell-connected device.

HTTP error 403 means "access to the page is denied". The continuing issue was not necessarily due to page caching, but because the content has been restricted by the site. It could be that during site repair, an ISP or even a locale has been blacklisted.
There are multiple servers at most web sites, and it could be that, as the site came back from repairs, DNS resolution was still directing your machines to a server that had not yet recovered, yet your cell connection was directed to a different IP. For example, looking up the address for google.com showed about 30 different IP addresses attached to that single domain name.
To test if that was the cause of the issue, in the unlikely event of a recurrence, change DNS resolution on one machine. For example, if DNS is set to automatic, specify a specific resolver, such as Cloudflare at 1.1.1.1, Google at 8.8.8.8 or other.
Some ISP's provide their own DNS resolution. At a public library, I found that Cloudflare was blocked, but automatic DNS resolution worked.

My original idea was the one you suggest - that they had multiple servers. But as more and more people reported success and I could not, I started looking at other possibilities.  As part of the diagnostic process with Google last night, I did in fact try setting the DNS to 8.8.8.8 on the router, and this did not help.  I am not sure how I would specify a specific DNS server for one machine.

nslookup provides the same answer when 8.8.8.8 instead of the default is specified.

To set DNS resolution, it depends on OS, but is quite easy in Windows, Mac, Linux and others. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-dns-server-settings-windows-mac-ubuntu-and-android/ and https://www.techtarget.com/searchnetworking/tip/Troubleshoot-name-resolution-on-Windows-Linux-and-macOS,

Thanks, I knew it was in there somewhere.  didn't look at the ipv4 tab.  In any event, doing that doesn't help.
